# Composer exclude from class map won't work on absolute path with symlink

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I have the following autoload:

```
  "autoload" : {
    "classmap": ["src/", "../library/project/src", "tests/mocks"],
    "exclude-from-classmap": ["../psl-library/project/src/Couchbase.php"]
  }
```

The result is as I expected - inside autoload_classmap.php I get this:

```
'Couchbase' => $baseDir . '/tests/mocks/Couchbase.php'
```

I have made a symlink from to the `../library/project/src` to `/var/www/html/include/library`

Then my autoload looked like as follows:

```
  "autoload" : {
    "classmap": ["src/", "/var/www/html/include/library", "tests/mocks"],
    "exclude-from-classmap": ["/var/www/html/include/library/Couchbase.php"]
  }
```

When running autoload I get an unexpected result:

```
'Couchbase' => '/var/www/html/include/library/Couchbase.php'
```

Any idea  what might be the problem when working with absolute pathes or with symlinks?

Comment: Why did you change the autoload definition? Using absolute paths makes it harder to use the project on other machines.

Comment: @Sven Yes you are correct, however I cannot "change the entire world" and unfortunately the dependency is not supported by composer, and on my development server it is in a different location than my local one.
Consider it a must.

Comment: Composer offers several ways to integrate dependencies even if the source does not provide the required information. It is some additional work, but I would think it is better to try to fix your problem inside Composer than to try fixing something around it. Can you share a bit more info about what kind of code you are trying to integrate? Where does it come from (SVN, Git, ZIP, "it was there")?

Comment: @Sven

The code is "just there" as you mentioned.
It is a shared library between several projects and I am not in charge of where it is :(
Otherwise I would just suggest to make it a zip library and require it and not autoload it.